# Why does the following theorem not hold if the function is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The theorem is that every strictly increasing or decreasing function is injective. So this means that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \iff x_1 = x_2$. However this should hold for every function if the function is continuous. However I do not see why it wouldn't hold if the function would not be continuous.

Comment: If $f$ is a constant function, say $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then it's continuous and not injective.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, but do we have an example of a strictly increasing non continuous function that is not injective ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly increasing or strictly decreasing implies injective. Continuity is not required.

To see this, suppose that $f$ is strictly increasing. Then $x < y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$, and $y < x$ implies $f(y) < f(x)$. Therefore, if $f(x) = f(y)$ we can't have $x < y$ or $x > y$. The only remaining possibility is $x=y$. Therefore $f$ is injective.

If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then apply the above argument to $-f$.